# docker-compose for a node project getting cannot find package.json on windows

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to get docker-compose working on my Windows 8 box.  I have the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  testweb:
    build: .
    command: npm run install
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/app/    
    working_dir: /app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

However when I run this using docker-compose I get an error saying cannot find package.json.  I know this is something to do with how the paths are mapped.  So I moved my folder to c:\users and tried with the same issue.  I then moved to c:\users\ and tried, ended up with the same issue.  The mapping on my virtual box is as follows

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Attached is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:7.7.2-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN apk update && apk add postgresql

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . .
```

Comment: It is actually looking for package.json inside the container. It has got nothing to do with your host file system. Can you post your dockerfile ?

Comment: I have pasted a copy of the Dockerfile.

Comment: Is there any error when you build the image ?

Comment: it gets created fine, however when I try to start it, it stops almost immediately.

Comment: For a docker container to stay up you need to have a running process. So you need to have a cmd or Entrypoint that will start a running process

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you set the working directory to `/app` in your docker-compose file, but your `package.json` is in `/usr/app`. So the container runs `npm run install` from the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

For a docker container to stay up you need to have a running process. In this case its the command `npm start` which will keep running as long as the container is up. So you need to have a cmd or Entrypoint that will start a running process. Please try something like this. Let me know if you have any questions

```
FROM node:7.7.2-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN apk update && apk add postgresql

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put file docker-compose.yml in project/app directory.
Then run `docker compose up` in project/app directory.

reference: https://forums.docker.com/t/use-docker-compose-in-get-started-tutorial-solved/129415